# how to publish a asp.net in visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

i am facing problem in publishing my project to host it on local host with the help of IIS. i have some questins

1. How to publish asp.net website in visual studio 2010?
2. after publishing and hosting which page of my website load first ?which i set in project set as start page or which have name index.aspx ?

i have tried many times to publish but am failed, when i published it do not show my code pages , kindly answer my problem

```
i have no error in my source code
```

Answer (score 1):

1. build as release so your code behind gets compiled into the DLLS
2. IIS looks for default.aspx if you have not defined any custom routing